# Implementing a VAE in pytorch - negative loss

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, loss-functions, autoencoders

So we can derive the loss function for the VAE following something like this: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.08956v1.pdf

But when I go to implement the loss function in pytorch, with MSE as the reconstruction error, I get an extremely large negative training loss. What am I doing wrong?